# Changing the background colour of a div in an iframe from the parent page isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have this in the `<head>` of the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#innerframe').load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find($(".TitleBG")).css("background-color", "red");
        });
    });
</script>
```

`<iframe src="/HomePage.aspx" onload="GetAlerts();" id="innerframe"></iframe>`

Then I have an example div in the iframe's .aspx page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-1 TitleBG">Drive</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 TitleBG">Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 TitleBG">Type</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 TitleBG">Format</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 TitleBG">Free Space</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 TitleBG">Available Space</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 TitleBG">Drive Size</div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the background-color property of the divs that have the class 'TitleBG', but my attempt doesn't seem to be working (above jquery)?

It works when I perform the `$(".TitleBG").css("background-color", "red");` on elements within the parent page, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is deprecated:

`$('#innerframe').load(function () {`

So I have to use this:

`$('#innerframe').on('load', function () {`

As after 1.8 it's (original code in question) no longer valid

Also:

> Instead of
>
> find($(".TitleBG")) use
>
> find(".TitleBG")

As user [Wiizl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228836/wiizl) states is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
find($(".TitleBG"))
```

use

```
find(".TitleBG")
```

Comment: Worked here... Both pages on the same domain?

Comment: Ahh my problem is it looks like this is deprecated: `$('#innerframe').load(function () {` so I have to use this: `$('#innerframe').on('load', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#innerframe').load(function () {
            var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#innerframe").contents();

            iFrameDOM.find(".TitleBG").css("background-color", "red");
        });
    });
</script
```

This will not work for third party iframes however.

Comment: It's another page in a child folder of the root directory, it's not external

Answer (score -1):

You can't alter a iframe page. It would be too easy.

You should consider making AJAX call and create DOM elements : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `You can't alter a iframe page. It would be too easy` you can when they're under the same domain

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my bad

Answer (score -1):

Try the actual id instead of `this` and change the find to `.find(".TitleBG")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#innerframe').load(function () {
            $('#innerframe').contents().find(".TitleBG").css("background-color", "red");
        });
    });
</script>
```